# pip install rpy2 does not work and produces error message concening compilation

Tags: python, rpy2

I had a problem with rpy2 and deleted it and tried to reinstall it, but when i use 'pip install rpy2' i get the following error message after a lot of compilation (at least i think that is what these lines show) lines:

Command `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/43/fyq0vxnd7wv9cs6ppt17fhsm0000gn/T/pip_build_Knödel/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/43/fyq0vxnd7wv9cs6ppt17fhsm0000gn/T/pip-82QEFh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/43/fyq0vxnd7wv9cs6ppt17fhsm0000gn/T/pip_build_Knödel/rpy2`

Storing debug log for failure in `/Users/Knödel/.pip/pip.log`

I tried to find a solution for this part:

```
--compile --user failed with error code 1
```

but couldn't find anything helpful

The debug log file didn't help me at all.

Python and GCC infos:
Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

I'd be thankful for any suggestion.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this your system's Python, or a Python you have installed on your own (binaries from python.org, homebrew, etc...) ? Installing packages over the system's Python is not recommended, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This may well be but i don't know how to check for this.
What fixed the problem was installing anaconda2 for the command line and installing rpy2 this way.